# Python os with pyautoGUi module

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I cannot get python to type "Hello world!" in the Notepad window when launching it via OS or subprocess. The "Hello world!" only gets typed after I close the notepad window, why would this be?

Code below:

```
import os
import pyautogui

os.system('"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"')
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can run notepad from the command prompt and then get the cursor back, `os.system` or even `subprocess.run` doesn't work that way on Python. Each waits until the process ID associated with your command is killed.

However, this code will work:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"')
# we want to give notepad time to appear.
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite("Hello world!")
exit()
```

There may be a more accurate command than time.sleep() to wait for Notepad to appear, something similar to WinWaitActive in AutoIt, and I'd be interested to hear it. But the above should work.

A possible workaround might be to create and then launch a new file in Notepad++ from the command line, or just to launch an already open instance of Notepad++ and have pyautogui send ctrl-n. I'm able to run multiple os.system calls in other scripts when opening text files in notepad++, as the process finishes once it find an open version of notepad++ to open the text file in.

```
echo > my_new_file.txt
os.system("my_new_file.txt")
```

os.system here cuts out once the file is launched, assuming Notepad++ was already open.